# Add Text to Excel Using EPplus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, export, epplus

I have a main directory which contains many sub directories. In each sub directory there will be images. I have managed to export images from each subdirectory into each excel spreadsheet in a excel workbook. For example, if I have 10 sub directories, there will be 1 excel workbook with 10 excel spreadsheets, in each spreadsheet there will be each sub directory's images.

What I want to accomplish now is if there is no image in any sub directory, the sub directory exported to an excel spreadsheet will be blank. I want to **add "No image found" to that blank excel spreadsheet as text.**

This is what I have tried:

```
 foreach (string subdir in filesindirectory)
        {
            string[] splitter = subdir.Split('\\');
            string folderName = splitter[splitter.Length - 1];
            ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet-" + folderName); //create new worksheet
            ImageCount = 0;

            if (Directory.GetFiles(subdir).Length == 0)
                {
                    ws.Cells["J9:L10"].Merge = true;
                    ws.Cells["J9:L10"].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
                    ws.Cells["J9:L10"].Value = "No chart to display";
                    ws.Cells["J9:L10"].Style.Font.Size = 16;
                }

            foreach (string img in Directory.GetFiles(subdir))
            {
                    ImageCount++;
                    System.Drawing.Image Image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(img);
                    var AddImage = ws.Drawings.AddPicture("Image" + ImageCount.ToString(), Image1 );
                    Image1 .Dispose();
                    // Row, RowoffsetPixel, Column, ColumnOffSetPixel
                    if (ImageCount > 1)
                    {
                        AddImage .SetPosition(ImageFinalPosition, 0, 2, 0);
                        AddImage .SetSize(770, 450);
                        ImageFinalPosition += (ImagePosition + 1); // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty row
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AddImage.SetPosition(ImageCount, 0, 2, 0);
                        AddImage.SetSize(770, 450);
                        ImageFinalPosition = (ImageCount + ImagePosition) + 1; // Add 1 to have 1 row of empty row
                    }
```

The problem I faced now is when I add the text to specific merged cells, if I view the spreadsheet with different screen size, smaller screen size will display text at centre of spreadsheet while larger screen size will display the text on the left of the spreadsheet.

This is a sample of what I see:

Smaller screensize(laptop):
[image]
Larger screensize(desktop):
[image]
This is the output I want to achieve(all screensize):
[image]
Please help me on this, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must understand how `foreach` loop works.. 
If your `count` is `0` your code in `foreach` doesn't run at all

You should put your checking before the `foreach` loop to write inside the worksheet

Put your code before the `foreach` loop as per below

```
if (Directory.GetFiles(subdir).Length == 0)   //if no image in that sub directory
{
    ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Merge = true;
    ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Top;
    ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
    ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f0f3f5"));
    ws.Cells["A1:A3"].Value = "content not found";
}

foreach (string img in Directory.GetFiles(subdir))
{
    // Your else code
}
```

Comment: hi @Nic, thanks for your help! I have managed to add the text successfully to excel. But there's an issue I faced here, if I put the text at specific merged cells, if I view the excel sheet using different screen size, smaller screen size will have the text appeared at the center of the sheet while larger sceen size will have the text to appear on the left. Do you know any workaround for this? Please look at my updated post thanks so much! :)

Comment: @FeliciaSoh Is very hard to cater for all Resolution which your image at middle.... If this is CSS then is easier but unfortunately this is Excel.... I believe that i'cant help you from this..

Comment: hi @Nic, oh I see.. understood thanks for your help anyway! :)